# Problem in test class

Tags: apex

How To cover below lines in test class.

```
    String iso = userInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
    String symbol = null;
    if(iso == 'EUR'){symbol='€'; }
    else if (iso=='ALL') { symbol='Lek'; } 
    else if (iso=='USD') { symbol='$'; } 
    else if (iso=='ARS') { symbol='$'; } 
    else if (iso=='AWG') { symbol='ƒ'; } 
    else if (iso=='AUD') { symbol='$'; } 
    else if (iso=='BSD') { symbol='$'; } 
    else if (iso=='BBD') { symbol='$'; }
    return symbol;
```

Comment: @Kedia what have you tried so far?

Comment: I write above code in apex class method now i want to cover above code in test class.

Comment: Hello Ravikant and welcome to Stackexchange! If you want to get an answer faster, better and more complete you should consider explaining you problem a bit more than "how to do it?". Simply explain your problem and show us what have you done so far in order to solve your problem. Questions with bunch of code and question like "can you help me?" remain unanswered most of the time. Help us us to help you, make your problem easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

In common, test class should create its own test user, 
simply to cover your code,  you can create one user without any currency code above.

But with best practice, i suggest you should create 9 users with diffreent currency code for test,
Let the test really make sence.

Comment: How i can create user using currency value can you tell me one example.

Comment: create user with this field :DefaultCurrencyIsoCode='sth'. Here is a full example http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

Comment: I am getting error like  Invalid field DefaultCurrencyIsoCode for SObject User

Comment: well, maybe you can start checking multiple currencies feature is enbaled for your org. DefaultCurrencyIsoCode  only applicable for organizations that use multiple currencies.